# I cannot emulate 3rd mouse button on MacBook

Tags: mouse

Attempting to use a trackpad without a 3-button mouse. From this forum and others I see going to Edit | Preferences | Input | Check emulate 3 button mouse
And choosing Emulate 3 Button Mo.. selecting either Alt or OS Key

Then, expected if I press G, then held the Command (Alt) or Globe/Fn key, I would see the graphic showing ability to snap to an axis. The graphic does not appear and holding the key has no effect.

Comment: You say "Then, expected if I press G, then held the Command (Alt) or Globe/Fn key". I don't know anything about Macs, but I thought that the Command key on a Mac was the equivalent of the Ctrl key, not the Alt key on a Windows machine?

Comment: I use a Wacom pen on my Mac and use the ALT-key, no need for the Fn-key. I would use that for the numpad to change views.